# Incorrect UI on KitKat with AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat, android-appbarlayout

I hate styling pre-lollipop devices.

As I understand, `AppBarLayout` won't go under statusbar.

My xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/gallery_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

            <com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout.SmartTabLayout
                android:id="@+id/viewpagertab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:stl_clickable="false"
                app:stl_customTabTextLayoutId="@layout/custom_tab_circle"
                app:stl_dividerColor="@android:color/transparent"
                app:stl_dividerThickness="0dp"
                app:stl_indicatorColor="@color/accent"
                app:stl_indicatorCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:stl_indicatorGravity="center"
                app:stl_indicatorInterpolation="linear"
                app:stl_indicatorThickness="8dp"
                app:stl_underlineColor="@android:color/transparent"
                app:stl_underlineThickness="0dp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My style:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="21">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="21">@color/navigationBarColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="21">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
</style>
```

And here some screenshots:
Android M
[image: correct]

Android KitKat

[image: incorrect]

Comment: hi! did you solve this issue somehow? I faced the same and opened the bug in the end https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=230859